# Cannot import javax.swing classes (in Android-studio project)

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm using Android studio.
I was trying to `import javax.swing.*;` for login page so I tried to write sentence to import which is import javax.swing.*;.

But nothing happen and the sentence to import despair.

Could you please teach me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Androids do not use the **swing** GUI classes.

Comment: I thought swing is for everything to set up login page.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access java swing class which is not a part of **android** SDK.

Answer (score 1):

It's an *Android* app! Why do you want to use things in the Swing framework? It doesn't make sense!

If you want to show a `JDialog`, try creating an `AlertDialog`. If you want the really convenient `javax.swing.Timer`, try this [class](https://gist.github.com/Sweeper777/85c61eb30d1deccbd664d91b6d4fdcc2) I wrote. Most Swing components have android counterparts!

There is no point in using Swing in an android app, because android doesn't support anything in Swing.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail.
I'm new to java programming then before started using Android studio,I used to use Eclipse.
and I could make JFrame.So I thought swing for every platform.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to import Swing framework into `Android SDK` and it can't work.
Android doesn't use Swing.

Comment: Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ Idea...
But you can't import it into android.

Comment: I see.
But seems I can't import anything to android studio.
I tried import android.os.Handler,import android app.;
I check it all day and still not fix it.